# Delete a cell results in deleting the whole column

Tags: excel, vba

I have weird situation. I have a sub that is supposed to check a cell for a value and keep deleting a cell preceding it until that cell finds the value.

When I run the following code, it will get to a line (row95 in this case) where col6 <> "Collect" and pauses so I can troubleshoot. I then [F8] step into the next line and instead of deleting the cell, it deletes the entire column.

```
Private Sub deletestuff()
    Dim i As Long
    
    For i = 2 To last("row", Sheet1)
        If Cells(i, 6).Value <> "Collect" Then
            Cells(i, 4).Delete shift:=xlToLeft
            Call deletestuff
        End If
    Next i
End Sub

Public Function last(ByVal parmType As String, ByVal sht As Worksheet) As Long
    Select Case parmType
        Case "r", "row"
            last = sht.Cells.Find( _
                what:="*", _
                LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                lookat:=xlPart, _
                searchorder:=xlByRows, _
                searchdirection:=xlPrevious _
            ).Row
        Case "c", "col", "column"
            last = sht.Cells.Find( _
                what:="*", _
                LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                lookat:=xlPart, _
                searchorder:=xlByColumns, _
                searchdirection:=xlPrevious _
            ).Column
    End Select
End Function
```

Context: "Collect" is in col8, so this code is supposed to delete a cell, restart and get to row95 and delete the next cell, then move along once col6 = "Collect".

Any ideas why the whole column is being deleted??

Comment: Could you share the code of the `last` function?

Comment: @VBasic2008 apologies. It's just a function to grab the last row or column number. I have added it to the original post.

Answer (score 0):

While I could not find the source of the bizarre behavior, I changed it from a recursion sub to a Do While Loop. It achieved the same result without ever deleting a column.

```
For i = 2 To last("row", sheet1)
    Do
        Do While InStr(1, orders.Cells(i, 4).Value, "Ship") = 0
            orders.Cells(i, 4).Delete xlToLeft
            j = j + 1
        Loop
    Loop Until j <= last("col", sheet1)
Next i
```